# How to do Text Color Transitions in WPF

Tags: wpf

It's easy in HTML using transition property.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
            p {background:black;color:yellow;transition:color 2s;}
            p:hover { color:red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>TEXT COLOR TRANSITION</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

In WPF it is done by the following. It needs a stop as fill behavior to rervert back to the Yellow on mouse leave:

```
<TextBlock Background="Black"
           Foreground="Yellow"
           Text="TEXT COLOR TRANSITION">
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:2"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    To="Red" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:2"
                                    FillBehavior="Stop"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Take a look at `LinearGradientBrush`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Wouter you use [`Stroryboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`ColorAnimation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimation(v=vs.110).aspx). What have you tried so far?